# Change VS2008 to use C# view

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

When I installed VS2008 and it asked me to pick my layout, I accidentally picked Web Development. Is it possible to go back and make it apply the C# layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

1. Go to Tools > Import and Export Settings...
2. Choose Reset all settings.  You'll be able to pick the settings again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools/Import and Export Settings/Reset All Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Tools->Import and Export Settings...
In the resulting dialog, choose Reset All Settings, then follow the prompts
(saving or not saving your current settings as you see fit) to Choose a
Default Collection of Settings and select C#